# Update querystring with comma separator in javascript

Tags: javascript, query-string

looking to "stackoverflow," I found this works:

```
function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
    var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=[^&#]*", "i");
    if (re.test(uri)) {
        return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value);
    } else {
        var matchData = uri.match(/^([^#]*)(#.*)?$/);
        var separator = /\?/.test(uri) ? "&" : "?";    
        return matchData[0] + separator + key + "=" + value;
    }
}
function removeQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value){
    var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
    var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
    if (uri.match(re)) {
        return uri.replace(re, '');
    }
}
```

It works fine, But I needed something similar with the only difference that the values are concatenated by a comma or any separator. Examples:

> www.google.com?key=1,2,3,4 and not key=1&key=2...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so what will be your input and what output should the code produce?

Comment: can you share a sample input and desired output in your question?

Answer (score 0):

this is my script code:

```
tjq('.servizio').click(function () {
        var servizio = tjq(this).data('id');
        var href = tjq(location).attr('href');
        if(tjq(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
            var url = removeQueryStringParameter(href, 'serv', encodeURIComponent(servizio));
            location.href = url;
        }else{
            var url = updateQueryStringParameter(href, 'serv', encodeURIComponent(servizio));
            location.href = href.url;
        }
    });
```

and html code:

```
<a href="#" class="servizio" data-id="'.$filtroS['servizio'].'">'.$filtroS['servizio'].'<small>('.$filtroS['quanti'].')</small></a></li>';
```

I am creating search filters.